# how to generate a <dialog> content depending by the pressed button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

im using a function to create react component, in the return, i've already my buttons and my hidden dialog.
i wish to call a function that returns the items that must be created inside the dialog depending on the button the user press.
i thought that i could directly insert the function call {generatedivcont(whatGenerate)} inside the dialog tag... or maybe 
to let the button call a function passing its value to it... but then i have no idea on how to return my json obj to the inside of dialog.. 
without using the DOM..innerHtml... 
could somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

An easy trick is that you can combine booleans and components.

```
{true && <IllBeShown />}
{false && <NothingToSee />
```

JS stops parsing as soon as it encounters false, thus the component doesnt get rendered.
Of course this isnt very handy like this, but you can replace the boolean with a function that returns a boolean, or a boolean variable:

```
Class Example extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        this.state = { isShown: false}
    }
    render(){
        return(
            {this.state.isShown && <Dialog />}
            <button onPress={()=>this.setState({isShown: true})}>Open</button>
        );
    }
}
```

---

If you want to pass information from `<Dialog />` back to `<Example />`, you can do that by passing a function for that. Also, it would be easy to close the modal, from within the modal:

```
Class Example extends React.Component{
    checkAndSaveData(data){
       // Something with the data:
       console.log("we've got something: ", data);
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <Dialog
                // In Dialog, to close: this.props.closeModal():
                closeModal={()=>this.setState{isShown:false}} 

                // bit weird name, but this ways it's more obvious to which function we point
                saveData={this.checkAndSaveData}
                settings={{color: 'blue', number: 42}}
            />
        );
    }
}
Class Dialog extends React.Component{
    render(){
        console.log("ww've gotten these settings: ", this.props.settings);
        const exampleData = {a:1, b:2, c:4, d:8};
        return (
            <div>
                <button onPress={()=>this.props.saveData(exampleData)}>saveData</button>
                <button onPress={this.props.closeModal}>Close</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**Note: I've written this from my head, it's untested*